# How to query array in vue store using Getters?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to pass an argument inside getters that should return the ID of the permissions but for some reason it is not returning anything.

```
////STATE
state: { 
  permissions: [
    {id: 1, name: 'Create User'},
    {id: 2, name: 'Delete User'},
    {id: 3, name: 'UpdateUser'}
   ] 
  }
//// GETTERS
getters: {
  getPermissionById: state => id => {
    return state.permissions.find(p => p.id=== id) // I tried with "=="
  }
}
```

And it is returning `getPermissionById:ƒ (id)` as result. I'm not quite sure what I'm missing here.

In component

```
computed: {  

...mapGetters('permissionStore', ['getPermissionById'])
}
```

I'm using vue devtool to check the state.

Comment: Can you show how you are calling `getPermissionById`?

Comment: @rcbgalido, I have update my code. I'm using vue devtool to check the data for now. Other  argument like filter is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of thing was [discussed here](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/issues/145) with [some input from Linus Borg](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/issues/145#issuecomment-273070775)

Why not just use a `getPermissions` getter to return the permissions array from state as-is? In your component's computed "permission" method, you could then use

```
return this.getPermissions.find(x => x.id === this.id) 
  ? this.getPermissions.find(x => x.id === this.id).id
  : someFallback

// or if you're using optional chaining...

return this.getPermissions.find(x => x.id === this.id)?.id || someFallback
```

If you need getPermissionsById to be a shared function, why not create a vuex action for that which accesses the state via the getter?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
computed: {  
  ...mapGetters('permissionStore', ['getPermissionById']),
  permission() {
    return this.getPermissionById(this.id)
  }
},
```

Comment: `permission:undefined`

Comment: Did you set a value for `id`?

Comment: How can I pass a value to id dynamically?

Comment: You can call the `getPermissionById` function anywhere in your code with an `id` parameter e.g. `getPermissionById(3)` and the function will return the object. For the code above, you can set the value of `id` and the computed property `permission` will be automatically updated (`this.id = <insert id>`).